# bootstrap tooltips not working when using it with angular ng-repeat and angular $interval together

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

**Question**: why isn't bootstrap like tooptips working when using it with angular ng-repeat and angular $interval

**Behavior I'm seeing**: when using bootstrap tooltips with angular ng-repeat and angular $interval, i am seeing the regular tooltips, not bootstrap like tooltips.

**What i've tried**:

1. if i use bootstrap tooltips with ng-repeat but disable the $interval, bootstrap tooltip works.
2. if i use bootstrap tooltips with $interval but remove ng-repeat, bootstrap tooltip works.

in the plunkr i've provided, lines 32, 33, you can disable/enable $interval for testing

http://plnkr.co/edit/6rUeJGsYfkgWMRrZoIYw?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="test">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>angular-test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({container: 'body', placement: 'bottom'}); // initialize bootstrap tooltips
    });

    var app = angular.module("test", []);

    app.controller("testCtrl", function($scope, $interval) {

        var stats = [{
                "name": "john",
                "stat1": 3,
                "stat2": 5
            }];

        var count = 0;
        $scope.getTestInfo = function() {
            $scope.count = count++;
            $scope.stats = stats;
        }

        //$scope.getTestInfo(); // if dont use interval, bootstrap tooltip works
        $interval(function(){$scope.getTestInfo();}, 1000); // if use interval, bootstrap tooltip doesnt work
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4" ng-controller="testCtrl" ng-init="count=0">
        <table id="table1" class="table table-hover table-condensed">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>column1</th>
                <th>column2</th>
                <th>column3</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="bg-info">
            <tr ng-repeat="stat in stats">
                <td data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{count}}">{{stat.name}}</td>
                <td data-toggle="tooltip" title="testcolumn2">{{stat.stat1 + count}}</td>
                <td data-toggle="tooltip" title="testcolumn3">{{stat.stat2}}</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When bootstrap's tooltip renders, no DOM for it is available yet (because you postponed it's creation via $interval). Another thing - after each time $interval fires you should tell bootstrap to update it's tooltip. I would suggest you looking at [angular ui Popover](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), it updates values automatically, so you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin are you able to show an example based on my plunkr on how to tell $interval should tell bootstrap to update it's tooltip?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AngularUI tooltip](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) which does all the work for you. Then your markup would look like this:

```
...
<tr ng-repeat="stat in stats" style="position: relative">
    <td tooltip="{{count}}" tooltip-placement="bottom" tooltip-append-to-body="true">{{stat.name}}</td>
    <td tooltip="testcolumn2" tooltip-placement="bottom" tooltip-append-to-body="true">{{stat.stat1 + count}}</td>
    <td tooltip="testcolumn3" tooltip-placement="bottom" tooltip-append-to-body="true">{{stat.stat2}}</td>
</tr>
...
```

See updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nlpDuT1sywtDoSHeXn1f?p=preview).